# Are Google API Key Application Restrictions Secure?

Tags: security, api, google-api

I believe an IP address or HTTP referrer can be spoofed, so can I trust that IP address or HTTP referrer application restrictions (configured via the Google API console) will prevent unauthorised parties from using my key?

Refer this StackOverflow question for background info: [How do I securely use Google API Keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625587/how-do-i-securely-use-google-api-keys)